# Access current url with the host name in Angular HTML

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i access the current url in template with Angular.

I tried this,

```
  <li><a href="../../profile?returnUrl="+router.url>Profile</a></li>
```

but it throws an error saying,

**Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '+router.url' is not a valid attribute name.**

Comment: Angular doesn't know you want it to interpolate that. Try `[href]=" '../../profile?returnUrl=' + router.url"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `{{router?.url}}`

```
<li><a href="../../profile?returnUrl={{router?.url}}">Profile</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your url is like this in your ".routing" file: /profile/:returnUrl

You can use this way instead of [href]: [routerLink]="['/profile', router.url]"

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JavaScript:

```
// Get current url
var url = window.location.href;

// Parse url
var splitUrl   = url.split('/');

// Get page name
var page = splitUrl[splitUrl.length - 1];
```

After getting page name you can set this `page` variable to the element in Angular or whatelse.

In jQuery:

```
$('li>a').attr('href', page);
```

In Angular:

```
var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('li>a'));
elem.attr('href','../../profile?returnUrl=' + page);
```

Comment: The angular solution you're proposing is for AngularJS (the tag is angularjs). Though the solution is complete, I suggest you to add the real solution to the above question, which should be angular 2+ related (the tag "Angular" refers explicitely to angular 2+).